# How can i create and view new django project in Bitnami DjangoStack?

Tags: django, bitnami

I installed the VMware Bitnami Django stack. But I do not understand how to use it.

How can i create and view new django project in Bitnami DjangoStack?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out.
Everything is done as well as in normal development.
[Example](http://www.informit.com/articles/printerfriendly.aspx?p=1175564)